# Scala count number of occurences of an element in a Map

Tags: scala

How would I count the number of occurrences of an element in a Map?

example

```
val myMap = Map("word1" -> "foo", "word3" -> "word4", "word5" -> "foo")

myMap contains "foo" count //???
// returns 2
```

Comment: @webSpider sorry, edited.

Comment: Why do you have the key `word1` in there twice? Do you realize that only one of those gets included in the map?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just use `count` with a predicate :

```
myMap.count({ case (k, v) => v == "word1" })
```

Alternatively:

```
myMap.values.count(_ == "word1")
```

Or even:

```
myMap.count(_._2 == "word1") // _2 is the second tuple element
```

Note: That's for values, not keys. Keys are unique.

Comment: About your second example : you can use `myMap.count(_._2 == "word1")`, saves you the `.values` call.

Comment: Using the `_2` tuple syntax is often considered "poor taste", but I added it in for completeness sake anyway -- thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In general, if you want to count occurences in a `Map` you can group by values and then transform the grouped submappings getting their size

```
scala> val occurrences = myMap groupBy ( _._2 ) mapValues ( _.size )
occurrences: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(word4 -> 1, foo -> 2)
```

This is handy if you need to have counts for every entry, and not only a single value.
Otherwise @Ven's solution is more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way,

```
myMap.values.filter { _ == "foo" }.size
```